# sitemap contains weird links and does not contain my pages

Tags: htaccess, seo, hacked, sitemap

I was about to submit my wordpress auto-generated sitemap to Google Search Console but I realized my sitemap contains weird links and it doesnt contain any of my actual pages. I checked example.com/sitemap.xml and example.com/wp-sitemap.xml and example.com/sitemap_index.xml. They all contain different weird links like :

```
<url>
<loc>https://example.com/armrests71n79/jsxc93911899.htm</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://example.com/ferocebotc/iq39894629.htm</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://example.com/hairspraysp6/ekqpmh46441760.htm</loc>
</url>
```

And this is just 3 of them. There are almost 1000 links like this and my site actualy has just 27 pages.
Extra information:

1. I recieved an htaccess attack in the past. At that times, my website was not wordpress and it was down because of that attack. After that I build the site with wordpress and it didnt go down anymore.
2. Some of the link in my sitemap redirects to weird websites. One of them redirects to a Japanese e commerce website
3. When I use a rondom sitemap generator (not plugin, from rondom websites) , they give the correct sitemap with 27 actual pages
4. I have tried plugins Yoast SEO, All In One Seo and got same result

Comment: Sounds like the site has been compromised, or that your previous attack was not cleaned up properly. You should not see sitemap files on the filesystem as WordPress/Yoast generate those dynamically. For help with Yoast SEO's sitemaps you will need to contact their support as that functionality is separate and 3rd party plugin support is off topic here. Random sitemap generators just crawl your site looking for links and generate a file based on what they found, they aren't the same as the sitemap WP or Yoast would generate in any way.

Comment: Aside: If you only have 27 pages and all pages are easily crawlable from the homepage (which would seem to be the case if an external tool is able to generate the report) then you don't strictly _need_ an XML sitemap. From [Google's help docs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451001): "If you have a small site (fewer than 100 pages) and you can reach any page on your site by following one or more links from your homepage, you don't need [to] use sitemaps or this report. In that case, simply request indexing of your homepage"

Comment: @TomJNowell The point is, issue is not only about Yoast or default wp sitemap generator. They both generate weird sitemaps. At this point, I didnt understand what you mean by sayin "Random sitemap generators just crawl your site looking for links and generate a file based on what they found, they aren't the same as the sitemap WP or Yoast would generate in any way. ". Why would it be different?

Comment: @MrWhite It might be a solution for now but this is a woocommerce based website so new pages will be added. The fastest solution I can think of now is to stop plugins generate sitemap and add sitemap manually. But the problem is even if I deactivate these plugins, I can still display sitemap at example.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Because the random site just browses your site and notes down what it found, that's not what WordPress or Yoast do. WordPress and Yoast use your database and the code to generate a sitemap, so pages that are published but not accessible by clicking around won't show on a sitemap spat out by a random generator, but they will show on the sitemap WP and Yoast generate. However, none of this is relevant if a sitemap XML with malicious URLs was uploaded to your host in the root directory. If you have malicious files listed in your sitemap then you have been hacked

Comment: I've closed this as hacked sites are off topic here and it's clear this is the result of a hack. Either you were hacked again, or, you did not clean up the damage from the last time.

Comment: @TomJNowell Well, I have already selected the tag "hacked". And also I mentioned it in the question. Maybe you should have let someone inform me about sitemap hacks before you close it. Obivously, question is not off-topic. Its just out of your qualification. Its another mystery how you decide "hacked sites are off topic here". Whatever!

Comment: The scope says hacked sites are off-topic, if you disagree with the scope or believe your question is not about hacked sites then you should post a question on the meta stack https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/